# Second derivative of a vanishing determinant

Tags: matrices

There is a matrix, whose components explicitly depend on two variables. For some values of these variables, the determinant vanishes. I need to compute analytically the second derivative of the determinant with respect to these two variables. The inverse matrix does not exist for these values of variables. I found a very nice relationship here
[Second Derivative of a Determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325807/second-derivative-of-a-determinant?rq=1)
However, it is based on the "modified" Jacobi formula for the first derivative, where the adjugate matrix has been replaced by a product of the determinant and the inverse matrix. I cannot apply it, because in my case the inverse matrix does not exist. If we dont'do this replacement, we will need the first derivative of the adjugate matrix. Does a relationship for the derivative of the adjugate matrix exist?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Singularity of the matrix is irrelevant to the question. Why do you mention that ?

Comment: This question is too allusive. You should give explicitly the matrix you are working on.

Comment: Compute it assuming the matrix is invertible. The final formula can be rewritten without using the inverse matrix. That will be the formula you want.

Comment: No, the final formula cannot be rewritten without the inverse matrix because the inverse matrix appears in the same monomials twice. Could you please see the link referred in my question?